# Ubuntu: Icon sticks to cursor

Tags: gnome, icons, cursor, docky

My cursor ends up dragging an icon around the screen, after some time of use. I'm running Ubuntu Gnome, and I'm suggesting that it has something to do with Docky, since the icons are coming from there.

Simply put, what happens is I make a tap or a long press on my left mouse button over an icon in Docky, and drag a little or a far, and the icon sticks to the mouse.

Is there anything I can do, to make this go away for good (a reboot is removing it, of course), or just be able to "clear" the cursor, without having to reboot?

[image]

Comment: If you disable Docky does this definitely stop?

Comment: If I disable Docky when it has happened, there's no effect - the icon attached to the mouse will still be there. If I disable it for good, there's no similar icon (or image) I can accidentally or on purpose, that I can drag around, which does have the same effect. So yes, the problem will go away without Docky, but that doesn't "clear" the mouse.

Comment: What about using xkill? So open terminal, type `xkill` and click on docky?

Comment: That does definitely kill Docky including the icon to disappear! That should work for a temporary solution, but if it leads towards anything that can make it permanent, or have other questions, be welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so it is definitely a bug with docky... Try reporting it on http://launchpad.net for now and I'll have a think about sollutions...

Comment: Same problem happens with clean 14.04. Without any docky.

Comment: are you still looking for answers?

Comment: No. I'm not using Docky anymore, so it might have been resolved in a newer version, I wouldn't know.

Comment: Off topic?? Gee.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me occasionally, but I just lock my screen and unlock it, and then the icon problem is resolved.

Comment: If it could save you time, just use xkill as described in the comments on my question, and reopen Docky. That's how I've went around it since Tim commented it, and it's not nearly as time consuming as locking and unlocking would be.

Comment: Still happening on Ubuntu 18.04 for the "Terminator" terminal program and locking and unlocking does solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Start Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and write command:

```
pgrep Docky
```

I had the same problem. But when I wrote above command in Terminal got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me I put the mouse back where the icon came from (the dock) and double click and it just puts the icon back on the dock.  I am using Kali Linux with Gnome though so not sure if the behavior will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue too when I start the system. Run following commands:

```
dpkg -l |grep -i nvidia  
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo reboot
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

enter tty1:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```